# Finding volume between two surfaces

Tags: matlab

I am plotting two 3d surfaces (s1 and s2). These two are part of concentric sphere. the code is below:

```
d=27*25.4;              
f1=6;                   
f2=4;                  
r1=2*f1*d;             
r2=2*f2*d;              

i=1;
for rho=0:(d/2)/19:(d/2)
     for theta=0:5:360
     x(i)=rho*cosd(theta);
     y(i)=rho*sind(theta);
     l(i)=(d/2)-sqrt(x(i)^2+y(i)^2);
     s1(i)=(r1-sqrt((r1^2)-(l(i)^2)));
     s2(i)=(r2-sqrt((r2^2)-(l(i)^2)));    
     i=i+1;
     end
end
figure(1)
tr=delaunay(x,y);
trisurf(tr,x,y,s1)
xlabel('x-axis');
ylabel('y-axis');
zlabel('z-axis');

figure(2)
tr=delaunay(x,y);
trisurf(tr,x,y,s2)
xlabel('x-axis');
ylabel('y-axis');
zlabel('z-axis');
```

Can we find volume between the two surfaces?

Comment: I'm quite uncertain how to go about this, are you sure that matlab would be suited for this? Seems like this would be simpler analytically perhaps.. Maybe try a simpler 2D example and see what techniques you could use to work it out

Comment: A first approximation would be to take the sum over all your grid elements `(x,y)` of `abs(s2-s1)` times the area of the grid element below